# Remove duplicates based on condition and keep oldest element

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, sql-delete

Currently, the table is ordered in ascending order by `row_number`. I need help removing duplicates based on 2 conditions.

1. If there is a `stage`, that is `online` then I want to keep that row, doesn't matter which one, there can be multiple.
2. If there isn't a row with `online` for that `org_id`, then I keep `row_number` = `1` which would be the oldest element.

| sales_id | org_id | stage | row_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ccc_123 | ccc | off-line | 1 |
| ccc_123 | ccc | off-line | 2 |
| ccc_123 | ccc | online | 3 |
| abc_123 | abc | off-line | 1 |
| abc_123 | abc | power-off | 2 |
| zzz_123 | zzz | power-off | 1 |

so the table should look like this after:

| sales_id | org_id | stage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ccc_123 | ccc | online |
| abc_123 | abc | off-line |
| zzz_123 | zzz | power-off |

[Looks like this, stackoverflow not working well with second table for some reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1wS3.png)

Comment: Please select the SQL variant you are using (Postgresql or MySql) to tag your question, not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a combination of a `CASE` statement to modify the rownumber of records with stage='online' and then use `ROW_NUMBER` to allow me to filter for the lowest value in a group.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1421b/5

```
create table sales_stage (
    sales_id varchar,
    org_id varchar,
    stage varchar,
    row_num int);

insert into sales_stage (sales_id, org_id, stage, row_num) values 
('ccc_123', 'ccc', 'off-line', 1),
('ccc_123', 'ccc', 'off-line', 2),
('ccc_123', 'ccc', 'online', 3),
('abc_123', 'abc', 'off-line', 1),
('abc_123', 'abc', 'power-off', 2),
('zzz_123', 'zzz', 'power-off', 1);
```

```
SELECT 
  sales_id, org_id, stage
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    sales_id, org_id, stage, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sales_id, org_id ORDER BY row_num) as rn
  FROM (
      SELECT sales_id, org_id, stage, 
      CASE WHEN stage='online' THEN -999 ELSE row_num END as row_num
      FROM sales_stage
    ) x
 ) y
WHERE rn = 1
```

[image: tabular results]